# JMeter : Extract range of values from json response

Tags: jmeter

Can you please let me know efficient way to extract range of ItemID's from below Json response and store extracted values in a variable with coma separated. Example: JsonResponse of a request. [ { "ItemID": "ITM40400002", "deliveryId": "1", }, { "ItemID": "ITM40400003", "deliveryId": "2", }, { "ItemID": "ITM40400004", "deliveryId": "3", } ]

If i pass range [0,1] it should extract first two items as below.
Extracted Variable Items = ITM40400002,ITM40400003
I have tried $..[0:1].id with match No: -1 and Compute concat checkbox enabled.but it is returning all id's

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor), example syntax would be something like:

```
[*].ItemID | [:2] | join(', ', @)
```

Demo:

[image]

This `[:2]` can also be a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you can make it dynamic.

More information:

- [JMESPath Tutorial - Slicing](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#slicing)
- [JMESPath Array Slice Expressions](https://jmespath.org/proposals/array-slices.html)
- [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I have tried using JSON JMESPath Extractor but it does not extract the values (ITM40400002,ITM40400003) in variable Value.     
Below is the snapshot i am using.    

Names of created varaible: Value
JMESPath expression: [*].ItemID | [:2] | join(', ', @)
Match No.(0 for Random): tried with -1 or 0

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: Try switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following code: `vars.put('foo', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).ItemID[0..1].join(','))`. You will be able to refer generated variable as `${foo}` where required. See [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) articles for more information if needed.